# How can I tune the PHP realpath cache?

Tags: php, optimization, require-once, realpath

Recent versions of PHP have a cache of filenames for knowing the real path of files, and `require_once()` and `include_once()` can take advantage of it.

There's a value you can set in your *php.ini* to set the size of the cache, but I have no idea how to tell what the size should be.  The default value is 16k, but I see no way of telling how much of that cache we're using.  The docs are vague:

[Determines the size of the realpath cache to be used by PHP. This value should be increased on systems where PHP opens many files, to reflect the quantity of the file operations performed.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.realpath-cache-size)

Yes, I can jack up the amount of cache allowed, and run tests with `ab` or some other testing, but I'd like something with a little more introspection than just timing from a distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've probably already found this, but for those who come across this question, you can use realpath_cache_size() and realpath_cache_get() to figure out how much of the realpath cache is being used on your site and tune the settings accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Though I can't offer anything specific to your situation, my understanding is that 16k is pretty low for most larger PHP applications (particularly ones that use a framework like the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com)).  I'd say at least double the cache size if your application uses lots of includes and see where to go from there.  You might also want to increase the TTL as long as your directory structure is pretty consistent.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer provided by Noodles, you can create a little test.php with the following code:

```
<?php

echo "<br>cache size: ".realpath_cache_size();
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>cache: ".print_r(realpath_cache_get(););

?>
```

Upload this to your site and navigate to it.  It will show you the amount of bytes currently being used by your cache, as well as what's actually in the cache.  This value is changing all the time so keep hitting that F5 button to get a better sense of where you're at.  It's a good idea also to do your testing during peak times.

If you see the value is frequently hitting your max cache size as defined in your php.ini then it's time to increase that value.

Keep in mind that the default PHP setting is 16K which is 16384 bytes.

Answer (score -3):

the 16K is the # of files not activity.

Set to 1k for most sites. Very similar to settings in APC, xcache ea etc.

Comment: This is incorrect, it refers to the amount of memory which is in use, see [realpath_cache_size()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath-cache-size.php), and [realpath_cache_get()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath-cache-get.php). I have it currently set to 16K, reported memory usage3 from realpath_cache_size() is 16317B, despite only having 140 files cached (counted from realpath_cache_get()), this is for a Drupal multisite and there are definitely more than 140 files which should be here. So 140 files are using the full 16K of memory.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.realpath-cache-size
> The size represents the total number of bytes in the path strings stored, plus the size of the data associated with the cache entry