# Is it possible to improve performance of php old architecture with php7 (realpath cache and opcache)?

Tags: php, caching, php-7.2, opcache, realpath

I have an old php architecture with conditional files requires/includes: that is if the program controller needs a component to manage a service it require/include the corresponding file. I tested it with php7 and it seems slower than with php 5.x version. I read that the problem could be the realpath cache that should be invalidated for each call to my application. I have more question about this problem:

1. is it possible to manage php configuration params to disable realpath cache? Does this make sense?
2. is it possible to enlarge cache size (4096K by default) to get all the possible require/include? I don't understand when the cache is invalidated.
3. is it possible to use some tip to reduce the cache reload with this type of architecture?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/q/197734/9811969 ?

Comment: Yes but he says how to check cache behavior but I need to guess when it is invalidated. May be an option make the cache size bigger to contain all the required path?